# libpng error undefined symbol png_read_image in unix

Tags: c++, unix, libpng

libpng error undefined symbol png_read_image in unix
i'm developing a program with C language in unix sco open server 5.0.7
and now, i need to use libpng in my project to load a png file
when i include  in my code (png.h and code are in same directory) and compile program there was no error.
but when i use png.h methods such as **png_read_image** or **png_sig_cmp** and compile it, compiler send me error:
undefined symbol png_read_image
amd other
can anybody help me?

Comment: did you link you program with libpng? if not, you have to pass -Lpng to compiler to do that

Comment: I linked lsocket when compling,how can i do multiple linking?<br>
and seems libong not installed correctly, how can i install it?

Comment: in same way as you link lsocket. For example: gcc -o myprogram myprogram.o -L/path/to/libpng.o -I/path/to/libpng/headers -lpng -lsocket .

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misleaded you. to link to some library you have to use -l flag. -L flag is to set path to this library

Comment: is this true? " cc evoip.c -Llibpng.a -lpng -lsocket

Comment: should be gcc evoip.c -L</path/to/lib> -lpng -lsocket
i.e. gcc evoip.c -L/usr/local/lib -lpng -lsocket

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is `cc`. Anyway you should pass the option to linker, not to compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include add library for compiling.

Example: `gcc -static myfile.c -L/user/local/lib -lmath -o execfile`

See the gcc syntax at http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc.htm